How to make exportable pie chart animation?
I have to make a loading pie chart in Blender to then later on be used in Unity and WebAR. I found a video making what I need here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gPJIW2NWcU
Here's my model, it needs to load from 0 to 75%:

Only problem is since it uses modifiers I cannot export it in a way where it's usable in Unity or WebAR.
Is there any other way I could make this?
